# react query refetches with old query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a **list component** that uses **react-query** to **fetch** the **list data** (in this case tickets)

```
<List
   fetch={{
     route: "tickets",
     queryKey: "tickets"
   }}
...
/>
```

The component fetches the data like so

```
const { isLoading, isError, data, refetch } = useQuery([queryKey], () => {
    return fetchEntity({ route: `${route}${window.location.search}` })
})
```

*fetchEntity does nothing else than using axios to fetch an return the data*

I'm also providing **window.location.search** to the route because I have a filter component that sets the filter to the url.

The filter works, but when I **refetch** (by refocusing the window), there are **2 different requests** in the network tab.

[image: queries]

One **with the filter params** and the other one **without the filter params**. Therefore, the list **shows the unfiltered data** for a few milliseconds and then the **filtered data** again.

I also tried to use the query like so

```
const { isLoading, isError, data, refetch } = useQuery([queryKey, window.location.search], () => {
     return fetchEntity({ route: `${route}${window.location.search}` })
})
```

This fixed the problem where the unfiltered data was shown for a few milliseconds. However, the old data is still fetched (maybe it is just faster now so not visible in the ui?).

**Can anyone explain this behaviour of react query?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was fetching with the same query key in a child component. That's why I had multiple requests.